# MongoDb Connector singleton pattern

Tags: java, mongodb, singleton

I am trying to implement a singleton pattern for connecting to my mongodb database so as to make sure i have only one connection.I have written following code '

```js
public enum MongoConnector {
 CONNECTION;

 private MongoClient client = null;

 /**
  * This function is used to create a single instance of the MongoDb connector
  * Thread Pooling is handled internally by MongoDb
  */
 private MongoConnector() { 
  try {
   client = new MongoClient();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();

  }
 }
 public MongoClient getClient() {
  if (client == null) {
   throw new RuntimeException();
  }

  return client;
 }
}
```

So i want to know if this is ensuring the singleton pattern.If not please let me know how it should be .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the MongoConnector is a singleton.